# Cannot add hyperlinks using golang with Jetbrains terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, hyperlink

I have these two attempts:

```
return au.Col.Hyperlink("foo", "https://example.com").String()
return au.Col.Hyperlink("foo", "https://example.com").HyperlinkTarget()
```

neither work - in both cases "https://example.com" is show and "foo" is hidden. If i switch them:

```
return au.Col.Hyperlink("https://example.com", "foo").String()
return au.Col.Hyperlink("https://example.com", "foo").HyperlinkTarget()
```

now foo is displayed of the `http://...` link, but foo is not clickable at all

I am using the aurora library here:
https://github.com/logrusorgru/aurora

And I alias locally so I can switch colors on/off:

```
package au

import (
    "os"
    "github.com/logrusorgru/aurora/v4"
)

var colors = os.Getenv("vibe_with_color")
var hasColor = colors != "no"

var Col = aurora.New(aurora.WithColors(hasColor))
```

Comment: can you please share the full data so it can be reproduced? what is au struct?

Comment: au is alias for aurora

Comment: so next question is to understand what is your main goal? what is the expected output?

Comment: expect a clickable hyperlink in the terminal console my G

Comment: hi, as far as i can see i can make it clickable but not colored in the terminal of inteliji, however in the regular mac terminal it seems fine.. will it be helpful?

Comment: sure, helpful, add an answer, I will upvote, ty ty

Answer (score 1):

Didn't manage to make it colored in JetBrains (in the Mac terminal it works).
However, in order to make it clickable you can do -

```
fmt.Println(aurora.Green("foo").Hyperlink("https://example.com"))
```

notice - Green is an example, you can use other color.
it will not look like a hyper-link but it will be clickable.
in Jetbrains it will look like (press control and you will be directed to the example url) -

[image: jetbrains]

in console it will look like -

[image: mac console]

Comment: yes seems like a bug/deficiency in JB terminal etc